# Book Recommendations on Quantum Mechanics and Quantum Information processing (with specific topics mentioned in the description)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations

I an an undergraduate in 2nd year of study and doing an internship this summer on Quantum information Processing and related concepts. Since I had very less exposure to Quantum mechanics I was suggested to read R. Shankar's "Principles of Quantum Mechanics". I am currently following the book . I am also asked to study about Density matrices and Liouville-Von Neumann equation for my project work. I'd like some book recommendations on Quantum Mechanics containing the mentioned topics . I was unable to find them on a Google search.

Comment: Why don't you ask your supervisor?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the book *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information* by Michael A. Nielsen and Isaac L. Chuang for a Quantum Information course and found it clear and providing good physical insight. I think it is quite self-contained and in the firsts chapters it provides an overview of Quantum Mechanics to understand Quantum Information. (In particular, it covers Density matrices too.)